# Combining artifacts in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I've looked through a fair number of these discussions with no success so far.

Our build process (on TeamCity 6.5.5) produces two folders, A and B.

We are currently zipping folder B for deployment (artifact path .\B => B-%build.number%.zip). However, it's been decided that folder A should be included as an archive in the zip of B. That is, following the build, B-2.0.0.zip should look like:

```
B-2.0.0.zip
    file 1
    ...
    file n
    A.zip
        file a1
        ...
        file an
```

To accomplish this, I've added the artifact path .\A => .\B\A.zip before the existing zip rule for B, so our artifact paths look like:

```
.\A => .\B\A.zip
.\B => .\B-%build.number%.zip
```

However, while A.zip is produced (I can see it in folder B following the build), it is not added to the archive B.zip. I looked at the build output, and the artifacts were created in the order expected.

Frankly, I'm stumped. Any insight would be well and truly appreciated. I could potentially modify the build script to accomplish this, but I'd rather not if at all possible.

Thanks in advance.

*Edit (2/24/12):*
On further research, it seemed like I was running into an issue with A.zip being created as a temporary file and moved into place after all artifacts were created.

So, I tried reordering my artifact paths as follows:

```
.\B => .\B-%build.number%.zip
.\A => .\B-%build.number%.zip\A.zip
```

I thought this would insert A.zip into B.zip. Instead of a nested archive, it creates a folder named A.zip. Am I just looking at a limitation of TeamCity not being able to nest archives?

Comment: I wanted something similar and could not find a good solution other than using the build script to produce a directory with the structure I wanted. Good luck

Comment: It's looking more and more like the solution, Mike. Thanks. Good to know it's not just me. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, TeamCity does not support complex packaging schemes for artifacts.
The way to go is indeed to add a build step to prepare the files to be published as artifacts.

Comment: That's a shame, but not entirely unexpected. Thanks, Yaegor!

Answer (score 9):

At least with version 9, it is now possible to add multiple files to the same zip file by doing something like this in the "artifacts paths" field:

```
.\A => myArchive.zip
.\B => myArchive.zip
```

Not sure though, if subfolders / sub-archives can be created on the fly ...

Comment: Super-relevant tip. My use case was exactly this; I confirm that this works in TeamCity 9.X.

Comment: Subfolders can be created this way: +:*/*.css => report.zip!/css/

Answer (score 3):

One option might be to use a Teamcity Service mesage to create the first archive before the build is finished.

```
##teamcity[publishArtifacts '.\A => .\B\A.Zip']
```

Then have team city give back the build artifact in the artifact packaging step in the build configuration:

Something like:

```
%env.TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH%\system\artifacts\%env.TEAMCITY_PROJECT_NAME%\%env.TEAMCITY_BUILDCONF_NAME%\%env.BUILD_NUMBER%\B\A.zip => .\B-%build.number%.zip
.\B => .\B-%build.number%.zip
```